# adding a property to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  // add the property to the object with a value of null
  // return the object
  // note: the property name is NOT 'property'.  The name is the value of the argument called property (a string)
}
```

I got a little stuck on an only home work question. I think I understand what its asking me to do. I want to pass in an object and add a new property and set its default value to null.

Here is what I have tried doing

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  // add the property to the object with a value of null
  // return the object
  // note: the property name is NOT 'property'.  The name is the value 
  object.property = property;
  object[property] = null;
  return object;
    }
```

This does not seem to be working the way I need it to as I believe I the object should produce something like

```
const object = {
propertyPassedIn: null,
};
```

can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: `function addProperty(object, property) { object[property] = null; return object; }` which you said you tried (at least part of your function did). What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  // add the property to the object with a value of null
  // return the object
  // note: the property name is NOT 'property'.  The name is the value 
  // object.property = property;
  object[property] = null;
  return object;
}

var obj = {x:1,y:null};
// undefined
obj
// {x: 1, y: null}
addProperty(obj, 'z');
// {x: 1, y: null, z: null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
object.property = property;
```

from your sample. This line would create a **ReferenceError** if the property is not already in the object. Other than that, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't do what you say you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  object[property] = null;
  return object;
}

    var obj = {
       key1:1,
       key2:2
    };

addProperty(obj, 'value');
this will give below result
{key1:1, key2:2, value:null}
```